# improving drawing pythagoras tree

Tags: java, optimization, java-2d, fractals

I have written program for drawing pythagoras tree fractal. Can anybody see any way of improving it ? Now it is 89 LOC.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {;

    public Main(int n) {
        setSize(900, 900);
        setTitle("Pythagoras tree");
        add(new Draw(n));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give amount of steps: ");
        new Main(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

class Draw extends JComponent {
    private int height = 800;
    private int width = 800;
    private int steps;

    public Draw(int n) {
        steps = n;

        Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
        setMinimumSize(d);
        setPreferredSize(d);
        setMaximumSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        int base = width/7;

        x1 = (width/2)-(base/2);
        x2 = (width/2)+(base/2);
        x3 = width/2;
        y1 = (height-(height/15))-base;
        y2 = height-(height/15);
        y3 = (height-(height/15))-(base+(base/2));

        g.drawPolygon(new int[]{x1, x1, x2, x2, x1}, new int[]{y1, y2, y2, y1, y1}, 5);

        int n1 = steps;
        if(--n1 > 0){
            g.drawPolygon(new int[] {x1, x3, x2}, new int[] {y1, y3, y1}, 3);
            paintMore(n1, g, x1, x3, x2, y1, y3, y1);
            paintMore(n1, g, x2, x3, x1, y1, y3, y1);
        }
    }

    public void paintMore(int n1, Graphics g, double x1_1, double x2_1, double x3_1, double y1_1, double y2_1, double y3_1){
        int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;

        x1 = (int)(x1_1 + (x2_1-x3_1));
        x2 = (int)(x2_1 + (x2_1-x3_1));
        x3 = (int)(((x2_1 + (x2_1-x3_1)) + ((x2_1-x3_1)/2)) + ((x1_1-x2_1)/2));
        y1 = (int)(y1_1 + (y2_1-y3_1));
        y2 = (int)(y2_1 + (y2_1-y3_1));
        y3 = (int)(((y1_1 + (y2_1-y3_1)) + ((y2_1-y1_1)/2)) + ((y2_1-y3_1)/2));

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawPolygon(new int[] {x1, x2, (int)x2_1, x1}, new int[] {y1, y2, (int)y2_1, y1}, 4);
        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x1_1, (int)y1_1);
        g.drawLine((int)x2_1, (int)y2_1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);

        if(--n1 > 0){
            g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x3, (int)y3);
            g.drawLine((int)x2, (int)y2, (int)x3, (int)y3);
            paintMore(n1, g, x1, x3, x2, y1, y3, y2);
            paintMore(n1, g, x2, x3, x1, y2, y3, y1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `pow()` in your code?

Comment: right, I was using it previously for printing results. Thanks. 112 LOC :)

Comment: You can get rid of some of the variable aliasing.  E.g., x2 is assigned x1 just for the sake of having a variable named x2.  You can combine it into something like `int x12 = (w/2)-(base/2);` and then `g.drawLine(x12, y14, x12, y23);`.  And save a line by declaring them as you define them.  That is, of course, if LOC is a larger concern than algorithm clarity.

Comment: Start your main method with the printout, and make the next line be new Main(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()); and you can eliminate the line where you declare the Scanner. Also, you can eliminate "int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;" and declare them when you define them.

Comment: I wonder, since you've mentioned lines of code twice, is that your only metric?  If so, I propose rewriting this as a code golf question.

Comment: no not only, clarity is also important but I had no idea how to improve that. So decreasing LOC's was easier. If you've got any suggestions on how I can improve the coding itself I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `drawPolygon` instead of multiply `drawLine`
- Remove the unused method `pow`,
- Clean up your imports
- Remove the unnecessary variables `h` and `w`
- put `--n > 0` into a one line
- do some reformatting

and there you go, 90 lines (comments still counted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {;

    public Main(int n) {
        setSize(900, 900);
        setTitle("Pythagoras tree");
        add(new Draw(n));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give amount of steps: ");
        new Main(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

class Draw extends JComponent {
    private int height = 800;
    private int width = 800;
    private int steps;

    public Draw(int n) {
        steps = n;

        Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
        setMinimumSize(d);
        setPreferredSize(d);
        setMaximumSize(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        int base = width/7;

        x1 = (width/2)-(base/2);
        x2 = (width/2)+(base/2);
        x3 = width/2;
        y1 = (height-(height/15))-base;
        y2 = height-(height/15);
        y3 = (height-(height/15))-(base+(base/2));

        //paint
        g.drawPolygon(new int[]{x1, x1, x2, x2, x1}, new int[]{y1, y2, y2, y1, y1}, 5);

        int n1 = steps;
        if(--n1 > 0){
            g.drawPolygon(new int[] {x1, x3, x2}, new int[] {y1, y3, y1}, 3);
            paintMore(n1, g, x1, x3, x2, y1, y3, y1);
            paintMore(n1, g, x2, x3, x1, y1, y3, y1);
        }
    }

    public void paintMore(int n1, Graphics g, double x1_1, double x2_1, double x3_1, double y1_1, double y2_1, double y3_1){
        double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        //counting
        x1 = x1_1 + (x2_1-x3_1);
        x2 = x2_1 + (x2_1-x3_1);
        x3 = ((x2_1 + (x2_1-x3_1)) + ((x2_1-x3_1)/2)) + ((x1_1-x2_1)/2);
        y1 = y1_1 + (y2_1-y3_1);
        y2 = y2_1 + (y2_1-y3_1);
        y3 = ((y1_1 + (y2_1-y3_1)) + ((y2_1-y1_1)/2)) + ((y2_1-y3_1)/2);

        //paint
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawPolygon(new int[] {(int)x1, (int)x2, (int)x2_1, (int)x1},
                      new int[] {(int)y1, (int)y2, (int)y2_1, (int)y1}, 4);

        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x1_1, (int)y1_1);
        g.drawLine((int)x2_1, (int)y2_1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);

        if(--n1 > 0){
            g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x3, (int)y3);
            g.drawLine((int)x2, (int)y2, (int)x3, (int)y3);
            paintMore(n1, g, x1, x3, x2, y1, y3, y2);
            paintMore(n1, g, x2, x3, x1, y2, y3, y1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, now I will just try to improve the coding. I was thinking about some better usage of recursion there.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it in [25 lines of F#](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2009/05/pythagoras-tree.html)? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
private int pow(int n){

    int pow = 2;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(n==0){
            pow = 1;
        }
        pow = pow*2;
    }
    return pow;
}
```

with

```
private int pow2(int n) { //Better name, to avoid confusion
    return 1 << n;
}
```

Although I can't see where you use this function.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to shorten the code (and the suggestions from Eric and Mihir are a good start), but I would focus on clarity.  Variables like x1 and y1 scream for a Point struct to hold these pairs together.  You could then pass these points in an array.